# new windows very slow to launch

Tags: unity, 14.04, nvidia, xorg

This problem shows up a day or two after rebooting. Launching any new window will be very slow. It comes up first with either just a transparent overlay or with the window grayed out and the rest of the system stalled. After maybe 30s to a minute the window will eventually show up fully. At that point everything works fine with no noticeable performance problems, until i need to launch another window. Also whenever I hit this problem, I also can't do anything within the system tray. The clock in the tray even stops updating. The system tray stays frozen whether i'm stuck launching a window or not. I don't see anything helpful or even recent in dmesg. Top doesn't show anything too unusual in cpu or mem usage, although I don't think its display is updating while the system is frozen waiting for a window to open.

Reboot and everything's back to normal.

Also this problem shows up suddenly. By that I mean everything is normal and then I try to open a window and its very slow to load. Its not like opening windows gradually gets slower over time.

This is on 14.04, nvidia 331 driver, unity.

Comment: what is the result of running `xdg-mime query default inode/directory` in terminal (<Ctrl>+<Alt>+<T>)?

Comment: ~ $ xdg-mime query default inode/directory yields 
nautilus-folder-handler.desktop

Comment: This is still an issue. Does anyone know of any any debugging probes or other feedback that might help resolve it?

Comment: No answer, but I'm having the same problem with an ATI card (radeon driver).

Answer (score 0):

Your issue may be caused by this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/1292467

Two suggested workarounds are:

```
 * Plug in external monitor after login
 * Boot with "video=LVDS-1:d"
```

Related:

[Very slow graphics performance after upgrade 12.04 => 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450555/very-slow-graphics-performance-after-upgrade-12-04-14-04)