# Samsung cn110 very slow with ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, system-installation

Hi I have a Samsung NC110, my system is 
Memory: 2 Gib
Processor Intel Atom CPU N2600 1.60 GHz8 x 4
Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 128 bits)
OS type 32-bit
Disk: 312.8 GB

Recently I upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, before my system was runing very nice but now is very slow.

How I can improve the performance of my system? It is possible to improve it?

Comment: have you checked http://askubuntu.com/questions/450555/very-slow-graphics-performance-after-upgrade-12-04-14-04?rq=1 ?

Comment: Do you know what graphics device you have?  Can you append your question with the output of `lspci | grep VGA`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your CPU is doing all the graphics rendering right now.

- You either need to enable the GPU to do that (Which I'm not sure **if** that is possible or **how**)
- Or you could switch to Lubuntu, Xubuntu or Kubuntu (w/o 3D Effects). You won't need to start installing from scratch. Installing lubuntu-desktop, xubuntu-desktop or kde-desktop will suffice.
- Or go back and re-install Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of tuning tips on the web, check here:

https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/speed

And try to improve the performance by changing the GPU driver, check the Manual from your PC wich GPU is in.

Comment: Is this topic solved for you?