# Stuck at "Starting adaptive readahead daemon preload [OK]"

Tags: 14.04, boot, nvidia

After upgrading to 14.04 from 12.04 my laptop (Asus X552c) got sluggish, especially when on Google chrome. So I was looking for a solution and found this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450555/very-slow-graphics-performance-after-upgrade-12-04-14-04).

I followed the instructions of user1429166 and did the following:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

but I didn't go for that "extra drivers" that  user1429166 suggested .. and rebooted and it was fine then I went for the extra drivers and changed the default one ( 'nouveau xorg server..') and set it to "Nvidia something..." and installed...  after that I tried to reboot but each time it's stuck forever at this:

```
* Starting Adaptive readahead daemon preload     [OK]
```

But I can still use

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>  to access tty and it just works fine but if I try  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>  to access the GUI screen, it doesn't work. So I reboot and we are back to the beginning.

I figured that it's of course something to do with that "Extra driver" thing that I did.

Someone please help asap !

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `grep -r edgers /etc/apt`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the PPA if it doesn't work for you

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

After that, the open source drivers will be used and you can use again your GUI.

If not, install the driver

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current nvidia-settings
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

After that you could ask a new question with a list of your hardware, especially your graphic.

Comment: I just went to the recovery mode and did "repair broken package" then I selected "enter in safemode" kinda something and it didn't work showed me error(1) and came back to the recovery mode option screen then I selected normal boot and it worked and took me to the "login box" that appears in gui mode. I entered my password and as if it was going to open the desktop but it didn't, showed me the login option again.. I tried 3 times didn't work then I chose "gnome metacity" mode and I am in. It worked but I am not sure if I reboot again things will be ok or will turn out to be mess again.

Comment: Oh yeah and my brightness control "fn+ f5/f6" is not responding now ! So a whole new problem but related for sure.

Comment: Reboot and try it again. Sorry :) if this doesn't work, we have all options to repair your system.

Comment: The keyboard problem has a low priority in this moment ;)

Comment: With which error message?

Comment: I am trying your solution and trying to purge the ppa but it fails:   warning couldn't find package list for ppa: xorg-edgers ppa

Comment: I am now trying to go back to "Using X.Org X server..."  because earlier I changed it to "Using Nvidia..." when following the instructions that I mentioned in my original question !

Comment: Ok, give me a ping after that.

Comment: After completing that I also did sudo apt-get autoclean and then also did tge autoremove thing... autoremove says: removing nvidia-prime (0.6.2)... removing bbswitch-dkms (0.7-2ubuntu1)... unistall beginning... etc etc

Comment: Rebooted and wow now I am in..smoothly ! Thanks a lot for being there all the time. I started to find a solution for my "sluggish system" (because of upgrading to 14.04) and got caught up in a bigger mess and you helped me clean this mess but I guess I have to start from the beginning... how to speed up tge graphics ! Another thing: looks like unity/compiz is gone ! And good news: brightness controller is back.